Binomial small deviations
For $n \geq 1$ and $\gamma \in
\left[\rule{0pt}{5mm}\,{0,1/\sqrt{n}}\,\right]$, define the two binomial random variables:
$$
X \sim \operatorname{Bin}\left(n,{1 \over 2} - {\gamma \over 2}\right)\quad
\mbox{and}\quad
Y \sim \operatorname{Bin}\left(n,{1 \over 2} + {\gamma \over 2}\right)
$$

I want to show that for this range of $n,\gamma$, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X \le
\left\lfloor{n \over 2}\right\rfloor\right)
-
\mathbb{P}\left(Y \le
\left\lfloor {n \over 2}\right\rfloor\right)
\ge
0.68\,\sqrt{\,{n}\,}\,\gamma
$$
Is there a standard result that will give me this or will I have to get my hands dirty with Stirling Approximations and such ?.
Berry–Esseen appears to be too crude due to the additive $1/\sqrt{n}$ error, which makes it inapplicable for $\gamma < 1/n$.


We can prove that your inequality holds and, in fact, the optimal constant is $c=0.682\ldots$.

Claim: For positive integer $n$ and $0\le\gamma\le1/\sqrt n$ then for $X\sim{\rm Bin}(n,1/2-\gamma/2)$ and $Y\sim{\rm Bin}(n,1/2+\gamma/2)$
$$
\mathbb P\left(X\le\frac n2\right)-\mathbb P\left(Y\le\frac n2\right)\ge c\gamma\sqrt n
$$
where ($\Phi$ is standard normal CDF)
$$
c=\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)=0.682\ldots.
$$

In fact, if we let $c_n$ be the optimal coefficient for each $n$, then this converges to $c$. So, it needs to be shown that it converges from above. This means that accurate approximations will be needed to the left hand side. The rate of convergence is of order $1/n$ for odd $n$ and $1/n^2$ for even $n$. For this reason, the case of even $n$ turns out to be harder, since a second order approximation in $1/n$ will be needed.
In the proof, I will rely on the following accurate lower bound for central binomial coefficients:
$$
2^{-2m}\binom{2m}{m}\ge\frac1{\sqrt{\pi m}}e^{\frac{-1}{8m}}\ge\frac1{\sqrt{\pi m}}\left(1-\frac1{8m}\right).
$$
This is the asymptotic expansion to first order from the Wikipedia page on central binomial coefficients, and is in fact a lower bound by results in "Asymptotic approximation of central binomial coefficients with rigorous error bounds"  by Richard P.  Brent (2016). From the same paper, we can see that the left inequality is exact to second order in $1/m$ (the right hand one ignores $1/m^2$ terms).
Proof:
If $Y\sim {\rm Bin}(n,p)$ and $X\sim{\rm Bin}(n,1-p)$ then $X\sim n-Y$ giving,
\begin{align*}
f(p)\equiv\mathbb P\left(X\le\frac n2\right)-\mathbb P\left(Y\le\frac n2\right)
&=\mathbb P\left(Y \ge \frac n2\right)-\mathbb P\left(Y\le\frac n2\right)\\
&=\mathbb P\left(Y \ge \frac n2\right)+\mathbb P\left(Y > \frac n2\right)-1\\
&=\begin{cases}
2\mathbb P(Y > (n-1)/2)-1,&{\rm for\ }n{\rm\ odd},\\
\mathbb P(Y > n/2-1)+\mathbb P(Y > n/2)-1,&{\rm for\ }n{\rm\ even}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and the claim is that $f(p)\ge2c(p-1/2)\sqrt n$ for $1/2\le p\le1/2+1/(2\sqrt n)$.
Represent $Y$ as follows: choose IID $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ uniform on $[0,1]$ and set $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n1_{\{U_i < p\}}$. As $p$ is increased, this jumps from $m$ to $m+1$ when $p$ passes through one of the $U_i$ and exactly $m$ of the remaining $U_j$ are less than $p$.  Hence, if we let $Z_i=\sum_{j\not=i}1_{\{U_j < p\}}$ then
$$
\frac{d}{dp}\mathbb P(Y > m)=\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb P(Z_j=m)
$$
for integer $m$.  However, the $Z_i$ are all distributed as $Z\sim{\rm Bin}(n-1,p)$ giving,
$$
\frac{d}{dp}\mathbb P(Y > m)=n\mathbb P(Z=m).
$$
We obtain,
$$
f'(p)=\begin{cases}
2n\mathbb P(Z=(n-1)/2),& n{\rm\ odd},\\
n\mathbb P(Z=n/2-1)+n\mathbb P(Z=n/2),&n{\rm\ even}.
\end{cases}
$$
As $Z$ has a binomial distribution, this can be written in terms of binomial coefficients.
Setting $A_n=2^{-2m}\binom{2m}{m}$ for $n=2m+1$ odd and $A_n=2^{-2m-1}\binom{2m+1}{m+1}$ for $n=2m+2$ even,
$$
f'(p)=2^{1+m}np^m(1-p)^mA_m.
$$
Note that $p(1-p)$ is decreasing on $p\ge1/2$, so $f$ is concave and it is sufficient to prove the claim at the end-point $p^*=1/2+1/(2\sqrt n)$. So the claim is that $f(p^*)\ge c$.
Substituting $p=1/2+x$,
$$
f'(1/2+x)=2nA_n(1-4x^2)^m
$$
Integrating,
\begin{align*}
f(p^*)
&=2nA_n\int_0^{1/(2\sqrt n)}(1-4x^2)^m\,dx\\
&=\sqrt nA_n\int_0^1(1-x^2/n)^m\,dx.
\end{align*}
In the limit $n\to\infty$ then $\sqrt nA_n\to \sqrt{2/\pi}$ and $(1-x^2/n)^m\to e^{-x^2/2}$ giving
$$
f(p^*)\to\sqrt{2/\pi}\int_0^1e^{-x^2/2}dx=2(\Phi(1)-\Phi(0))=c.
$$
So the constant $c$ is optimal in the limit. The claim then is that $f(p^*)$ tends to $c$ from above.
Odd n: For $n=2m+1$ odd, the inequality $(1-x^2/n)^m\ge e^{-x^2/2}$ for $x^2\le1$ can be shown by checking that the derivative of $e^{x/2}(1-x/n)^m$ is positive. So,
$$
f(p^*)\ge \sqrt{n}A_n\int_0^1e^{-x^2/2}dx=\sqrt{\pi n/2}A_nc.
$$
The claim now follows whenever
$$
\sqrt{\pi n/2}A_n\ge1.
$$
Plugging in our bound for central binomial coefficients,
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\pi n/2}A_n&\ge\sqrt{(2m+1)/(2m)}(1-1/(8m))\\
&=\sqrt{(1+4y)}(1-y)\\
&\ge1
\end{align*}
for $y=1/(8m)\le1/8$ for $m\ge1$. This proves the claim for odd $n > 1$. The remaining case for $n=1$ is $c_1=A_1=1 > c$.
Even n:
For $n=2m+2$ even, we need to accurately bound $(1-x/n)^m$ from below. To do this, expand as a power series in $y=1/n$,
\begin{align*}
(1-x/n)^m\exp(x/2) &= \exp(x/2+(1/(2y)-1)\log(1-xy))\\
&=\exp\left(x/2-(1/(2y)-1)\sum_{k\ge1}x^ky^k/k\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\sum_{k\ge1}\left(\frac1k-\frac{x}{2k+2}\right)x^ky^k\right)
\end{align*}
All coefficients of $y^k$ in the exponent are positive, so we also have positive coefficients if the exponential is expanded. Keeping only terms up to $y^2$ therefore gives a lower bound,
\begin{align*}
(1-x/n)^m\exp(x/2)
&\ge1+(1-x/4)xy+(1/2-x/6)x^2y^2+\frac12(1-x/4)^2x^2y^2\\
&=1+\frac x4(4-x)y+\frac{x^2}{96}(96-40x+3x^2)y^2.
\end{align*}
Replacing $x$ by $x^2$ and integrating wrt $x$ from $0$ to $1$ (setting $\alpha=\int_0^1e^{-x^2/2}dx=\sqrt{\pi/2}c$),
$$
\int_0^1(1-x/n)^mdx\ge\alpha\left(1+ y/4+(1/32+1/(8\alpha\sqrt e))y^2\right).
$$
This is done by repeated integration by parts (or Wolfram alpha...).
We need to show that $f(p^*)\ge c$ where $f(p^*)$ is the integral above multiplied by (plugging in our lower bound for central binomial coefficients)
$$
\sqrt{n}A_n=\frac{2m+1}{2m+2}\sqrt n2^{-2m}\binom{2m}{m}\ge\frac{2m+1}{2m+2}\sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi m}}e^{-\frac1{8m}}
=\frac{1-y}{\sqrt{\pi (1/2-y)}}e^{-\frac y{4(1-2y)}}.
$$
So,
$$
f(p^*)/c \ge \frac{1-y}{\sqrt{1-2y}}e^{-\frac y{4(1-2y)}}\left(1+y/4+(1/32+1/(8\alpha\sqrt{e}))y^2\right).
$$
It can be seen that this is greater than $1$ for $0\le y\le 1/4$ or, equivalently, $n\ge4$. This proves the result for even $n\ge4$. The only remaining case $n=2$ is given by $c_2=\sqrt2 A_2=\sqrt2/2 > c$.
QED
Note:
You might suspect that a stronger bound holds:
$$
\mathbb P\left(X\le\frac n2\right)-\mathbb P\left(Y\le\frac n2\right)\ge \Phi(\gamma\sqrt n)-\Phi(-\gamma\sqrt n)
$$
That is, it is bounded below by the case where $X,Y$ are normal with mean $n/2\mp n\gamma/2$ and standard deviation $\frac12\sqrt n$. For odd $n$, the proof above should follow through without much change, so it looks like it holds there. But, for even $n$, the lower bound for our integral involved some integration by parts to give the coefficients of $y$ and $y^2$, so these will be different if the integral is over a different range, and I don't think the improved inequality does hold.
